# ListView & onItemClick - When click, open new activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

actually my ListView is here:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);                 
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ls);

lv.setAdapter(ad);
```

What I want is when I click on an item in my ListView it should open a new activity for that item where I can show some description of the item e.g. if the item would be a BMW M6 than in the new acticity should be things like hp, 0-100 etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried `setOnItemClickListener` on listview??

Comment: or did you override `onListItemClick` in case your class extends either `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`

Comment: I will try setOnItemClickListener right now... that i will answer again.

Comment: answer is available from official documentation; author didn't bother to do any prior research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a new Activity you have to use intents :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
```

You can add extras :

```
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

And to start the activity :

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Now if you wan to do it when you click on an item of your list you'll have to use :

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener();
```